# count number of items in Hashmap

Tags: java, arrays

```
List<String> keyList = new ArrayList<String>();
keyList.add("2015GeneralAndroid");
keyList.add("2016GeneralAndroid");
keyList.add("2015AdminAndroid");
keyList.add("2015AdminAndroid");
keyList.add("2016AdminAndroid");
keyList.add("2016AdminIOS"};
```

1. I used Hashmap to avoid duplicates.
2. But i need output 2015GeneralAndroid as "1" and 2016GeneralAndroid as "1". So total count 2.
3. These ouput should have to return when i'm passing parameter as GeneralAndroid then output should be 2.

   I need this output:

   ```
      If i submit General then GeneralAndroid = 2. (it should be calulate with per count per year. so Ouput result is 2).
      If i submit AdminAndroid then AdminAndroid =2.
      If i submit AdminIOS then AdminIOS=1.
   ```

Comment: *"I used Hashmap"* No you didn't. You used `ArrayList`.

Comment: `I used Hashmap to avoid duplicates.` ... actually you should use a _set_ if you want to filter out duplicates.

Comment: So is rule to always ignore the first four digit year, but retain the remainder of the string?

Comment: True! @TimBiegeleisen or else you have to iterate while adding and check the .contains method then if does not exist then add otherwise don't add.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Except the double `"2015AdminAndroid"` only counts once, apparently.

Comment: By using set we can filter but if i pass parameter like GeneralAndroid then it should calculate as 2. if the data is 2015GeneralAndroid and 2016GeneralAndroid @Tim

Comment: What is result if you submit `Admin`?

Comment: What is result if you submit `2015`?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily solve this using a `Stream`:

```
public long countElements(String needle) {
    return keyList.stream()
         .filter(s -> s.contains(needle))
         .distinct() //use if you want to have distinct results, e.g. AdminAndroid=2
         .count();
}
```

Then just call it:

```
System.out.println(countElements("AdminAndroid")); //prints '2'
```

Comment: But `AdminAndroid` prints `3` and OP wants `2`.

Comment: That would be the use of the `#distinct` call

Comment: keyList is arrayList. so i'm not getting stream like that.

Comment: You can do exactly that, but you should not be using a rawtyped list. `List<String> keyList = new ArrayList<>();` would be more proper

Comment: AdminAndroid 3 is there. but before data 2 values with 2015 and 1 value value with 2016. if 2 values are there for 2015 also. i need that 2015 as 1 count and 2016 as another count. totally 2 only AdminAndroid

Comment: @harika How can `2015` be count 1, when there are 2 unique (3 total) strings with `2015` in them?

Comment: I think you're trying to say calling this with `"AdminAndroid"` would print 3, when it does in fact print 2.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it as follows in Java8

```
        Set<String> keySet = new HashSet<>();

        keySet.add("2015GeneralAndroid");
        keySet.add("2016GeneralAndroid");
        keySet.add("2015AdminAndroid");
        keySet.add("2015AdminAndroid");
        keySet.add("2016AdminAndroid");
        keySet.add("2016AdminIOS");

        String input = "GeneralAndroid";

        Long count = keySet.stream().filter(e -> e.contains(input)).count();
```

Note that I have used a `Set` to avoid duplicates

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a bit speculative, but assuming that each of your strings is prepended with four digit year, and that being duplicate means the remainder of the string (minus the year) matches another string, then you can try this logic:

First add everything to a set:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add("2015GeneralAndroid");
set.add("2016GeneralAndroid");
set.add("2015AdminAndroid");
set.add("2015AdminAndroid");
set.add("2016AdminAndroid");
set.add("2016AdminIOS");
```

Then create a map to actually count things:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (String str : set) {
    String key = str.substring(4);
    Integer cnt = map.get(key);
    int val = (cnt == null) ? 1 : cnt.intValue()+1;
    map.put(key, val)
}
```

Finally iterate over the map to get your result:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: But looking up `AdminAndroid` finds `3` and OP wants `2`.

Comment: @Andreas This most certainly _does not_ find 3 for `AdminAndroid`.  This is the purpose of first filtering through a set.  Please remove your downvote.

Comment: @Andreas But is it clear what the set is doing?  There are two layers of duplicates, first raw duplicate entries (with the year in front), and then duplicates which arise _after_ the year has been removed.

Comment: I'm still pondering the *"If i submit `General` then `GeneralAndroid = 2`"*, and how that fits with any implementation using Set/Map.

Comment: @Andreas LOL sure let me go ahead and add some full text search capabilities to my code :-)

Comment: So far, [answer by Rogue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40670347/5221149) is only answer that gives right response to all input, as far as I've been able to interpret question. Of course, it doesn't use Set/Map, but sequential text search through entire list, but output seems good.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see you using HashMaps. Also, to avoid duplicates, you could have used Sets.

You may keep the values in a HashMap and get the count for each value by using following:

```
int count = Collections.frequency(new ArrayList<String>(hashmapObject.values()), "2015GeneralAndroid");
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to do something like this:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Item>> hMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<Item>>();
 int hashSize;
  /* 
      Some Operations
  */
 hashSize = hMap.size(); // This will give the total no. of items in HashMap
```